# underscore/lodash - combine objects with same elements

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to for lack of better terms 'zip' or 'merge' json objects based on a single reoccurring element in each. Example:

```
var obj = {
    CATS:[
        {
            id:123,
            LIST:[
                {result1:CAT1},
                {result2:CAT2}
            ]
        },
        {
            id:987,
            LIST:[
                {result1:CAT3},
                {result2:CAT4}
            ]
        }
    ],
    DOGS:[
        {
            id:123,
            LIST:[
                {result1:DOG1},
                {result2:DOG2}
            ]
        },
        {
            id:987,
            LIST:[
                {result1:DOG3},
                {result2:DOG4}
            ]
        }
    ]    
}
```

I would like to use the 'id' nested within the obj to create:

```
var new_obj = {
    123:[
        CATS:{
            LIST:[
                {result1:CAT1},
                {result2:CAT2}                    
            ]
        },
        DOGS:{
            LIST:[
                {result1:DOG1},
                {result2:DOG2}                    
            ]            
        }
    ],
    987:[
        CATS:{
            LIST:[
                {result1:CAT3},
                {result2:CAT4}                    
            ]
        },
        DOGS:{
            LIST:[
                {result1:DOG3},
                {result2:DOG4}                    
            ]            
        }
    ]        
}
```

Not partial to LoDash or Underscore... happy to use whatever works.
Thanks!

** Caveat! Must be ie8 compatible. Bleh! **

Comment: Your desired output has invalid structure. The value of the key `123` is supposed to be an array, yet is populated with key-value pairs. Did you mean `123` to be an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, after some trial and error, I MIGHT have what you need...

```
var result = _.reduce(obj, function(memo, group, key) {
  var ids = _.map(group, function(g) {
    return g.id;
  });

  _.each(ids, function(id) {
    var obj = {};

    obj[key] = {};
    obj[key].LIST = _.filter(group, function(g) {
      return g.id === id;
    }).map(function(g) {
      return g.LIST;
    })[0];

    memo[id] = (memo[id] || []);

    memo[id].push(obj);
  });

  return memo;
}, {});
```

Check it out working... http://jsbin.com/gabako/1/edit

Comment: Folks, we have a contend-ah! @jcreamer898 yr result is correct... but is it the best way? +1 for your speedy answer. On your way to a checkmark...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you intended the value of the `123` key in the output to be a hash rather than an array, then without either underscore or lodash:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce(                              // Reduce the keys in the input
  function(result, animals) {                         // by taking each key like DOGS
    animals.forEach(                                  // and for each of its
      function(animal) {                              // elements (animal)
        result[animal.id] = result[animal.id] || {};  // create an ID field in result
        result[animal.id][animals] = animal.list;     // add animal's list of results
      });
    return result;                                    // and pass result to next key
  },
  {}
);
```

For IE8, use relevant polyfills. Or do the obvious rewrite using underscore/lodash equivalents.

Comment: Love the fact that you are NOT using either library... but I need it to be ie8 compatible. I do believe .reduce() and .forEach() are not applicable. Sorry for not mentioning before.

Comment: If you're not already using shims, you should be. See https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.